# Terraform - Environment Handling Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, terraform, environment

I am trying to create DNS records for my various environments but for production I would like to use the apex domain directly; for most environments it returns dev or tst but I'd like for prd to return just the apex domain, without the environment subdomain

Currently:

run.tf

```
# Create Environment Hosted Zone
resource "aws_route53_zone" "r53_zone_env" {
    name    = "${var.Env}.${var.ApexDomain}"
}
```

This returns = **dev.google.com** or **tst.google.com**

I tried something along these lines with no luck:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "r53_zone_env2" {
    comment = "dummy"

    dynamic "name" {
        for_each = var.Env != "prd" ? [] : ["1"]
        content {
            name = "${var.Env}.google.com"
        }
    },
    dynamic "name" {
        for_each = var.Env == "prd" ? [] : ["1"]
        content {
            name = "google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

R,

Answer (score 1):

Create a `local` variable

```
locals {    
    domain = var.Env == "prd" ? var.ApexDomain : "${var.Env}.${var.ApexDomain}"
}
```

and then use it via

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "r53_zone_env" {
    name = local.domain
}
```